# Field level permissions using CanCanCan or Pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-admin, pundit, cancancan

I am currently using Rails 4.1.14 with CanCanCan 1.13.1 and defined granular permissions on model/record level.  Admins can manage all articles but users can edit only articles they authored.

To prevent regular users for editing specific fields I make fields visible in rails_admin depending on role.

```
visible do 
  bindings[:object].id == bindings[:view].current_user.roles.include? :admin
end
```

I am also using https://github.com/aasm/aasm gem and created custom actions so user can move records into new states.

But what I really want is to enable field level permissions depending on user's role / record.  I can't find any docs on CanCanCan or https://github.com/elabs/pundit pages.

Does anyone have experience with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean that an admin should be allowed to edit all fields of a record, but an editor is only allowed to change the fields x and y?

Yes, this is possible in pundit, since it integrates with strong parameters (which you should be using anyway). There's also an example in the [pundit readme](https://github.com/elabs/pundit/blob/master/README.md) (see: Strong parameters). I simplified example from the readme:

```
# post_policy.rb
def permitted_attributes
  if user.admin?
  [:title, :body, :tag_list]
else
  [:tag_list]
end

# posts_controller.rb
@post.update_attributes(permitted_attributes(@post))
```

the `permitted_attributes` helper in the controller is provided by pundit and automagically calls the `permitted_attributes` method of the infered policy.

Comment: simple and great solution